# Using Word macro to insert portion of filename in header?

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to insert a portions of Word file name into its header. E.g., we have Word docs with filenames such as

```
'01 00 50 Instructions to Bidders.docx'
```

and would like to parse off '01 00 50' and put it in part of the header and 'Instructions to Bidders' in another. I found some VB macros that parse that insert the filename and parse it, e.g.,

```
Sub InsertFileName()
    Selection.InsertBefore Text:=Left(ActiveDocument.Name, _
      Len(ActiveDocument.Name) - 4)
End Sub
```

but the above macro inserts text at the cursor location. I need to break it up and locate it in specific parts of the header like this

```
Smith Building Renovation                                    01 00 50
42 Main St.               Instruction to Bidders          Page 1 of 5
Augusta, ME                                               23-Feb-2014
```

Breaking up the file name in VB is clear to me, but how do you locate parsed text in specific parts of a document?

Comment: Will the format of the filename always be the same? Ie will it always be in the format `nn nn nn Filename.docx`?

Answer (score 0):

If the beginning of your filenames always have the same format; Ie `NN NN NN Filename.docx` then this should work;

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

Dim j As Long
Dim str As String
str = ActiveDocument.Name
Dim strRight As String
Dim strLeft As String


strRight = right(str, Len(str) - 9)
strLeft = left(str, 9)

For j = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(j)
        .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = strRight + " middle " + strLeft

    End With
Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, edit includes being able to use both parts of filename. Bit messy but will do the job.

Comment: Many thanks for the efforts! They're helpful though I see now I wasn't clear on the crux of my problem of locating parsed text in specific locations of a header. I updated my question to show more what I'm after.

Comment: Ok so you just want the first part (the numbers in your example) to be in the header? Will the numbers always be in that format (NN NN NN)?

Comment: Yes. I got something working using DOCPROPERTY. The VBA updates the document properties "Title" and "Category" using the Left and Right parsing you recommended and then I use the DOCPROPERTY field to put them in my header. So far it does what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a suggestion, using custom document properties can be useful in this situation if you want to retain use of the builtin properties for their "intended" purposes (especially "Title"). But IMO there is a lot to be said for using Document variables and DOCVARIABLE fields instead, especially if you do not want your users to be able to alter their values easily.